# jQuery toggle class animation on parent for multiple similar elements

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I have a series of divs which I am using css to animate. Each div has a button inside that triggers a css animation. I want to use jQuery to add a css transition class to the div so that it animates independently. The trick is that I need to allow for multiple divs to be active/animated/up at once. I want to use the same js for each instance, but I want the divs to act independently and not affect each other. I'm using:

```
$(".show").click(function() { 
    $(".show").parent().toggleClass('rise');
    });
```

Here's what I've got now:

http://codepen.io/interwebjill/pen/PzZzMW

Comment: `$(this).parent().toggleClass('rise');`

Comment: Beautiful. 'this' is the answer. You should post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(".show").click(function(event ) { 
  $( event.target).closest("div").toggleClass('rise');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at your codepend and this is what I'd recommend:

```
$('#card-container').find.(".show").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('rise');
});
```

- This constrains the event binding to the card-container, just in case some other element on the page uses the `show` class
- And uses `closest` instead of `parent` in case the show` link is nested deeper than the 1st level